# RailsEnv misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rvm, ubuntu-14.04

I am following this link http://blog.redpanthers.co/2015/10/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-in-ubuntu-14-04/ in order to install ruby on rails with rvm and passenger. I was fine until I got to configuring my demo.conf file using this command sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/demo.conf. When I tried to change RailsEnv production to RailsEnv dev or RailsEnv development it says that perhaps RailsEnv is misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. I tried to change this setting because the link says its necessary to be in the development environment in order to see the welcome aboard page. I dont know how to give you a copy of my error log file as I am running ubuntu 14.04 server on vmware and I can't copy out of that. I have pastebinit installed, so if anyone knows how I can copy code from the error.log file to show you why I am getting this error, please advise. Also I would like to know how to configure the acccess control as I am using apache 2.4 and the link im following isnt very clear. I would appreciate any help on this as I am doing it for a college project and I am hitting many walls with completing this installation. please bare in mind I am new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

`RailsEnv development` AND restarting apache should do the trick:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I tried that but i had to install a library with the following command to stop this error apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger. I am still having issues connecting to welcome aboard page for ruby on rails. my DNS server is configured as virtualmachine2.khufunet.com as I am creating this environment on vmware. virtualmachine2 is the actual name of my host. I have 4 services (cups server, dns server, ssh server and ruby on rails server) on the one virtual machine running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: cups dns and ssh server are working fine. i am wondering as my dns nameserver is virtualmachine2.khufunet.com would that have any affect on how I should configure my virtualhost file for my test application for testing ruby on rails. I tried configuring the virtual host file settings for ServerName as virtualmachine2.khufunet.com and then tried it as www.khufunet.com and neither are responding. If i put virtualmachine2.khufunet.com into a browser it shows the apache2 welcome page. any suggestions would be appreciated as I am at a complete loss here.